# Trying to fix nested forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, dom

I am trying to write a fix for my client's problem - his main form, which is rather large and spans many tabs, has includes to content which include modal forms (so if you have a list of widgets associated with your profile, a popup form could allow you to add another). The modals aren't working because they create a form within a form, so I thought I could just push them down to the end of the page like this:

```
$('body').append('#modalFormID');
```

But this isn't working because it seems like the browser is stripping the 2nd form tag out of the DOM before document.ready can fire.  I've created a [jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/2znqsev9/):

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks,

Rob

Comment: That's right. The DOM has to be valid, so if the HTML is invalid the browser will rewrite it itself when parsing. And jQuery operates on the DOM, not the original source code.

Comment: To add onto Barmar's comment, instead of modifying the DOM with jquery, you could try modifying the original HTML code so that the form within a form problem doesn't exist in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

ok, here is what I'm thinking.  Inside the includes, wherever there is a form, I'll wrap it in a div tag which also includes data attributes for the action and method like so:

```
<div id="wrap_form1" class="formwrap" data-action="/myscript.php" data-method="POST">
<form action="/myscript.php" medhod="POST">
... form stuff...
</form>
</div>
```

with something in the global page script to resurrect the form if it gets erased by the browser.

```
  $('div.formwrap').each(function() {
    if (!($(this).find('form').length) {
      var formtag='<form class="nestedform" action="'+$(this).attr('data-action')+'" method='+$(this).attr('data-method')+'>';
      $(this).html(formtag+$(this).html()+'</form>');
    }
  })
```

and then we still have to move it down so it is outside of the main form.

```
  $('form.nestedform').each(function() {
    $('body').append($(this));
  });
```

Any thoughts?